# GAE unowned JPA relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have an unowned relationship in my Domain model

```
@Entity
public class A {
 @Id
 private String id;
 private Key firstB;
 private Key secondB;

 // getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class B {
 @Id
 private Key id;
 private String name;
 // getter & setter
}
```

`KeyFactory.createKey(B.class.getSimpleName(), name)` is the way I generate the Key for class B

I save B independently from A and assign it to an instance of A some time. The problem is that after saving A both fields *firstB* and *firstA* are null.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For reference, the question relates to this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Unowned_Relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key` objects are not persisted by default so require explicit annotation which is why you are seeing `null` values.

Try annotating `firstB` and `secondB` as `@Enumerated` (this should really be `@Basic` but [there is a bug which prevents this from working](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html#Class_and_Field_Annotations)):

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Enumerated
    private Key firstB; 

    @Enumerated
    private Key secondB;
}
```

**Update:** The latest SDK and DataNucleus JARs now correctly allow the use of @Basic.

Comment: As it turns out with the latest SDK and the latest datanucleus jars, @Basic works as well.